# Submenu disappeared quickly in vue js application

Tags: html, css, vue.js, html-lists, nav

Hi Everyone I'm facing a small issue where on hovering the menu item in nav-bar the sub-item appears but quickly disappears. The user is unable to select the desired option. WHAT i actually want is to hold it (sub-menu) item while the user hovers it.

**Following is HTML and CSS code of my application:**

**HTML CODE**

```
<template>
    <div class="navigation">
         <v-toolbar extended extension-height="10" color="blue">
            <v-row>
              <v-col cols="6" class="nav-el hidden-md-and-down" > 
                  <div class="navbar">
                     <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Products ▾</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown">
                                <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li> <hr>
                                <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li> <hr>
                                <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li> <hr>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  </div>
                </v-col> 
       </v-row>
      </v-toolbar>
    </div>
    </template>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
.navigation{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30;
}
.navigation .nav-el{
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;  
}

.navigation .navbar li{
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px; 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
  font-size: large;
  position: relative;

}
.navigation .navbar a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color : white;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}
.navigation .navbar a:hover{
  background-color: rgb(89, 160, 241);
}
.navigation .navbar .dropdown li {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 9px;
  background-color: rgb(89, 160, 241);
  min-width: 120px;
}
.navigation .navbar .dropdown li a{
  background-color: rgb(89, 160, 241);
}
 .navigation .navbar .dropdown{ 
  position:absolute;
  opacity: 0.9;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  display: none;

}
 .navigation .navbar li:hover ul.dropdown{
   display: block;

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to do it completely with CSS? Rather you can show/hide with Vue. On hover set a flag like "showMenu" to visible, and only on click (either on menu item or anywhere on the page) you hide it.

Comment: I'm not famiiar with Vuetify. Other think is.. check if your BODY is filling the screen. If your BODY is too small, the toolbar may hide its submenus when mouse out of the <body>. Can set the body tag min-height to viewport height.

Comment: thanks a lot i was unaware of these vue functions you solved my problem :)